# How to clear EOF flag in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have small and primitive code reading a file - the file's content is appending from another application though - it's something as Linux utility [less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)). It works fine, but if the reader reaches EOF, the "EOF" flag of the file is set. Then any other read operations on the file lead to empty read/unchanged size of file (`hFileSize`, `hTell`). The solution would be to call [clearerr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clearerr) or [rewind](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) - they clear the EOF flag, I suppose. How to do it in Haskell? And if there is some way, is it possible to do it in cross-platform way (if it is not cross-platform)?

PS. Currently I reopen the file, but I think that permanently reopening during poll, with period of 1-2 seconds maybe is not so good idea if there are better solutions.